# How to subscribe to a component variable in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I ma using the header for my server url and i declared it in one of the component and i want to use that header in all components where ever i had a server call but i failed to subscribe to that header,can anyone please help me

my interface component,

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 @Injectable()
export class Config {

 header = 'http://localhost/a2server/index.php/';

}
```

my main.ts(here i want to use the header)

```
 var data :any;
  constructor(public location: Location,public config:Config,public router: Router, public http: Http, fbld: FormBuilder,public toastr: ToastsManager) {

    this.config
        .subscribe(header => this.data = data); 
      console.log(this.data)
```

i know that i am wrong ,can someone please help me

injectable,

```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
  import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
  import {Component} from '@angular/core';
  import { IDetails } from './details';
 import { Config } from '../headers';
 @Component({
   providers: [Config]
})
@Injectable()
 export class GetCustInfo {
   header:any;
   str = localStorage.getItem('social');
   loc = JSON.parse(this.str);
   id = this.loc.profile_id;
    constructor(private _http: Http,public config:Config) {  this.header = this.config.header;}
 private _productUrl = this.header+'profile/editcustominfo/'+this.id;
getCustList(): Observable<IDetails[]> {
    return this._http.get(this._productUrl)

.map((response: Response) => { 

    return <IDetails[]> response.json().data[0]; 

    });

}
```

}

Comment: Where do you provide Config? Do you get an error message. You can only subscribe to an Observable not to a string. See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: ohk,so i cannot subscribe to a string ...

Comment: here i want that header in all the components,gunter can you give any solution

Comment: To declare config variable and use it every where you can declare opaque-token as explained on https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dependency-injection.html#!#opaque-token

Comment: If you provide `Config` using a modules provider list you can inject the `Config` everywhere and access the header like shown in my answer (or you can use a token like mentioned by @ranakrunal9 and inject the string directly instead of wrapping it with a service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You subscribe to observables. For a simple string you just access the property:

```
var data :any;
  constructor(public location: Location,public config:Config,public router: Router, public http: Http, fbld: FormBuilder,public toastr: ToastsManager) {

    console.log(this.config.header);
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. What are you trying to accomplish? What problem do you encounter? What do you mean with "keep"?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "keep providers".

Comment: sorry gunter,i just added an interface to my code(edited) and there i added providers .Is that the right way?can you see it please

Comment: No, `@Component({
   providers: [Config]
})` needs to be added to a components class. You can't just put it anywhere. It has to be immediately before the class where it should be applied to.

Comment: An injectable is not a component. You put either `@Injectable()` on a class or `@Component()` but not both at the same time. I suggest you check the tutorials at http://angular.io

Comment: therefore how can i get this providers

Comment: into an injectable class

Comment: Providers don't need to be on an injectable class. Providers just define the scope of instances. You can add providers to (< RC.5) `bootstrap(AppComponent, [/*providers here*/])` (=> RC.5) `@NgModule({ providers: [ /*providers here*/], ...])` or on components `@Component({ selector: '...', providers: [ /*providers here*/], ...])`. If you add it to a component one instance of the injectable is shared between this component and its descendants. If you provide it at `bootstrap()` or `@NgModule()` one instance is shared with the whole application.

Comment: `@NgModule()` is only >= RC.5 the other methods work with RC.2

Comment: Gunter ,i added my provider->Config like this 
bootstrap(MyDemoApp, [Config,
    provideForms(),
    disableDeprecatedForms(),
    APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS,Navbar,
    { provide: LocationStrategy,Config, useClass: PathLocationStrategy },
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    provide(ToastOptions, { useValue: new ToastOptions(options) }),
]);   but not working

Comment: do i need to import anything?